# RestSharp - StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to post a new customer to a web api.  When I execute the following in Fiddler I get no errors:

```
POST https://api.someurl.com/api/businesses/99999999/contacts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: api.someurl.com
Authorization: TOKEN json:{"authenticationCode":"kLJBlaUCK0pYY6YXI6qB3CHamq0=","expiryDate":1468083160641,"locale":"en_US","myUserId":88888888888,"restriction":null,"site":"api.someurl.com"}
Content-Length: 931

{"business":9999999999,"collaborationContext":0,"contactInformation":{"campaign":null,"city":"SomeCity","country":"SomeCountry","email":"email@someurl.com","fax":null,"first":"FName","hasShippingAddress":false,"instructions":null,"last":"LName","locale":null,"mobile":null,"name":"FullName","phone":"222.333.4455","postalOrZipCode":"90210","provinceOrState":null,"readOnly":false,"referral":null,"registration":null,"shippingCity":null,"shippingCountry":null,"shippingName":null,"shippingNotes":null,"shippingPhone":null,"shippingPostalOrZipCode":null,"shippingProvinceOrState":null,"shippingStreet1":null,"shippingStreet2":null,"street1":null,"street2":null,"tollFree":null,"url":null},"currency":null,"defaultTaxCode":null,"id":0,"incomeOrExpenseAccount":null,"linkedBusiness":null,"payableAccount":null,"paymentAccount":null,"paymentTerms":null,"prefix":null,"receivableAccount":null,"removed":false,"type":"CUSTOMER"}
```

When I try to execute (what I think is) the equivalent (see below), I get "StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType, Content-Type: text/xml, Content-Length: 0)"

```
private static string PostContact(string busId, Contact contact )
        {
            var restClient = new RestClient("https://api.someurl.com");
            var jsonToken = GetJsonToken();
            // var contactJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
            var req = new RestRequest("/api/businesses/{business-id}/contacts");
            req.Method = Method.POST;
            req.Parameters.Clear();
            req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.AddUrlSegment("business-id", busId);
            req.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format("TOKEN json:{0}", jsonToken), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
            req.AddParameter("application/json", contact, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var resp = restClient.Execute(req);
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
            return resp.Content;
        }
```

Is there a special order to adding parameters or headers, or am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `User-Agent` header in the Fiddler request?

Comment: @EvanMulawski it works without User-Agent (201 Response)

Comment: It might be a serialization issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687229/moving-from-standard-net-rest-to-restsharp

Comment: @EvanMulawski it acutally wasn't using the JsonConvert.SerializeObject (I just commented it out for clarity) - RestSharp is serializing it

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
///request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("undefined", JsonRequest, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = client.Execute(request);
var responseJson = response.Content;
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the original problem with the code from the question?

Comment: Please don't only answer with a block of code. Instead, explain what your block of code does and how it resolves the issue. This is not very useful to anyone besides the OP because if their situation is not exactly the same as this one, it's not immediately clear how they can apply this to their own situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have another easier solution:

Add this single line (if NO file is attached)

`req.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;`

In my case a piece of source code look like this:

```
   var client2 = new RestClient("https://myurl.com/api/site/Create");
   client2.Options.MaxTimeout = -1;`

    var request2 = new RestRequest("https://myurl.com/api/site/Create", Method.Post);

     request2.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ _authstr);
    // AddFile below, therefore commented out
    // request2.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
     request2.AddParameter("PFolderId", "a1c1w000000GR5hAAG");
     request2.AddParameter("Title", "MyTitle5");
     request2.AddParameter("GeoRegion", "{E|BE|BRUXELLES-BRUSSEL}");
     request2.AddParameter("SeismicZone", "0");
     request2.AddFile("file", "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Drawing.png");
     RestResponse response2 = client.Execute(request2);
```